# How to use meta to get data from all the links in a website

Tags: python, scrapy

As I am new to python I need your help . I need to crawl data from all the links in a website. I used meta to go into the link and to get data. When i use my code i can get from only one link.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import urlparse
from alibaba.items import AlibabaItem
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import conversion
import re




class RedditCrawler(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'baba'
    allowed_domains = ['http://india.alibaba.com/']
    start_urls = ['http://india.alibaba.com/supplier_list.htm?SearchText=automobile+parts&bizType=1']
    custom_settings = {
        'BOT_NAME': 'alibaba',
        'DEPTH_LIMIT': 8,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 0.5
        }


    def parse(self, response):
        s = Selector(response)
        next_link = s.xpath('//a[@class="next"]/@href').extract_first()
        full_link = urlparse.urljoin('http://india.alibaba.com/',next_link)
        yield self.make_requests_from_url(full_link)
        item=AlibabaItem()
        item['Name']=s.xpath('//div[@class="corp corp2"]//h2/a/text()').extract()
        item['address']=s.xpath('//div[@class="value grcolor"]/text()').extract()
        item['Annual_Revenue']=s.xpath('//div[@class="attrs"]//div[2]//div[@class="value"]//text()').extract()
        item['Main_Markets']=s.xpath('//div[@class="attrs"]//div[3]//div[@class="value"]//text()').extract()
        item['main_products']=s.xpath('//div[@class="value ph"]//text()').extract()

        full_link1=s.xpath('//h2[@class="title ellipsis yrtil"]/a//@href').extract_first()
        absolute_link = urlparse.urljoin('http://india.alibaba.com/',full_link1)
        request_variable = scrapy.Request(absolute_link,callback=self.parse_website,dont_filter=True)
        request_variable.meta['parcel_stuff'] = item
        yield request_variable

    def parse_website(self,response):
        s = Selector(response)

        item = response.meta['parcel_stuff']
        item['Year_Established']=s.xpath('//table//tr[4]//td//a[@class="message-send mc-click-target"]//text()').extract()

        yield item
```

Answer (score 0):

You've based your RedditCrawler on CrawlSpider which already has a parse() of its own. Change your class to RedditCrawler(scrapy.Spider). The docs are [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Rule), but the important part is

> Warning
>
> When writing crawl spider rules, avoid using parse as callback, since
>   the CrawlSpider uses the parse method itself to implement its logic.
>   So if you override the parse method, the crawl spider will no longer
>   work.